# Having a single Eclipse installation, where simultaneous sessions are started up with different JDK installations, or different ini configurations

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-tool-suite

Giving STS as an example.

I wish to have only one single installation of Eclipse STS 3.9.7. Normally I run more than one session of Eclipse/STS. I need to have

- a couple sessions started on JDK 8
- a session on JDK 10
- another session on JDK 11

I also have an Eclipse 2018-12 installation. I wish to have only one such installation, from which I wish to start

- a session in JDK 9
- another session in OpenJDK 10

The only way I know how to specify the JDK is by specifying it on the ini config file. Perhaps there is another way. Therefore, currently I have multiple replicated copies of Eclipse/STS installations, each specified to start up from a different JDK.

Having proliferation of Eclipse/STS installations of the same version is very undesirable and confusing. Especially when I need to install or update modules from the Marketplace across all of them.

Is there a better way than having multiple replicated installations, in order to variously specify the JDK/bin/javaw paths to start up each of my sessions?

Comment: Why do you really care which version of Java is running Eclipse itself? You care about which version of Java is used by your projects, but that's defined by the project and/or workspace.

Comment: Running multiple sessions of the same Eclipse installation is a bad idea, since Eclipse caches files in the installation folder, and that'll be all messed up if you run multiple sessions. Use one session per installation, and learn to live with it.

Comment: "Use one session per installation, and learn to live with it" Are you sure you know how Eclipse works? A programmer who has only one Eclipse session?

Comment: You can use the `--launcher.ini xxx` command line option to specify a different config.ini file.

Comment: I wonder why in this scenario multiple sessions are necessary: with a JDK 11 via the `--release` option as JDK 8 gives you compiler errors in both cases: if using stuff added after Java 8 and if using stuff removed in Java 9, 10 and 11.

Comment: @BlessedGeek Yes, I know how Eclipse works. I have many Eclipse sessions, each with a different workspace, and each with a different installation. In the past, I've had weird results running multiple sessions of the same, so I keep one installation = one workspace, and disable to workspace prompt on startup.

Comment: I've never had weird results having multiple sessions on a single installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `--launcher.ini <path>` command line option to specify a different 'config.ini' file to use when starting Eclipse.

Comment: The ini has to be within the Eclipse installation, otherwise Eclipse will croak "shared lib not found".

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to [`--launcher.ini <path>` already mentioned by greg-449](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54003280/6505250), there is a trick that works without any command line argument:

**Copy the executable** (`eclipse.exe` on Windows, `eclipse` on macOS and Linux) **and** the **`eclipse.ini`** files. When you execute the renamed executable file, the correspondingly renamed `.ini` file instead of `eclipse.ini` is used.

Comment: I made a hard link.